# Message Received When Attempting To Tag

Tags: tags, facebook-timeline

I am receiving this message: "Your Request Couldn't be Processed: There was a problem with this request. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can." when attempting to tag something I posted in my Timeline. This is such annoying as I am trying to let all my family and friends of my daughter in-law and son arrival of their baby. I have been trying to tag for since the birth on 24 -26 and giving it hours to see if this problem has been fixed and still to no avail. This is something that should have been resolved as soon as it was reported yet it has been 2 days. Please fix this problem as I do not want to have to send each person a message stating this Blessed Event on the Eve of Christmas... I have tried to see if it was just due to using Chrome so I tried tagging on Fox as well as IE yet to no avail. **So** I know this is a genuine problem not of mine but solely of Facebook. facebook-timeline